# Import 71 and file permission in ArcGIS

Tags: permissions, gis

I am making a map for my thesis. While using ArcGIS, I must use Import71 to convert some .e00 files (In this particular case, political boundaries and Hydrography networks). When I select my output folder, I receive the message:

> E:\ File Path" This file cannot be accessed. Make sure you have
>   security privileges on the drive.

I use Windows 7. Is this simply a Windows/administrator problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: most likely it is a permissions problem.  I'd create a subdir on the e: drive and assign permissions to that.

Answer (score 0):

Import71.exe doesn't always work in Windows7, but at least one person reports success (see comment). You might try *import71.exe > r-click > Troubleshoot compatibility*; didn't work for me personally, though I didn't try every available option.

The command line [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) from the gdal utilities suite can translate the files just fine on windows 7 though:

```
ogr2ogr out_dir test.e00
```

Install from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki

Comment: 1. `Import71.exe` works just fine for me under Windows7 64-bit. 2. `ogr2ogr` works, but it is orders of magnitude slower than `Import71.exe`. The former can take hours to convert an 8MB file, while the latter completes the operation in under 10 seconds.

Comment: @Gili your two sentences oppose each other. Which one is the typo? ;-) It's good to know that at least for some import71.exe does work on Win7; wish I understood why not for me.

Comment: Matt, I'm saying both tools work for me but `ogr2ogr` is substantially slower than `Import71.exe`. Try running as admin and/or installing into a path without spaces. Otherwise, sorry I don't know.